# WPF Data Binding without using Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm unfamiliar with the .Net environment and I am currently working on a project that involves manipulating the data in a Microsoft Access DB. I have done some tutorials to get a grasp of how to go about the project but running into a problems.

What I would like to know is if I can bind the data from the DB to a datagrid in a WPF project without using the Entity Data Model Wizard. I would like to create a menu in which a user can navigate to their local copy of their Access DB and open it from there. And then from there, bind the data to the grid.

Any help will be much appreciated. And thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. You can issue direct SQL calls if you like such as:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

        var conString = "MyConnectionString";

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            con.Open();
            var sql = "Select Name from Customer";

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var c = new Customer
                    {
                        Name = reader[0].ToString()
                    };

                    Customers.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Then you can bind your DataGrid to that Customers Collection in the XAML.

Comment: Forgot to vote this as answer. Thanks @Kelly, it worked!